# React native flatlist only with video is not loading video after some items

Tags: performance, react-native, video, loading, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist that has only video items. After some scroll, the video items do not loading any more.

What could be happening? Does flatlist can not have multiple video items?

Comment: Can you provide us with your code so we can understand your problem better?

Comment: I got it! I just changed the video library. It looks like the library I was using was in trouble